# 5-element clipboard for copy+paste

Tags: python

This is some code that I wrote for fun because in some of my classes I had to copy and paste between different Google docs I had. So, I decided to write a python script that would let me copy up to 5 different pieces of text and paste them.

I feel like the code is really inefficient and too verbose, though. Specifically, is there a better way of writing the paste functions so that I could generalize past 5 copied items? Clearly, with what I have I would need to add another function in order to copy and paste up to 6 things, etc.

I am a bit worried that this script would be useless to anyone that didn't have `pynput` and `pyperclip`. Please critique this and let me know how I can code better!

```
from pynput import keyboard
import sys
from pyperclip import copy, paste
from time import sleep

class React_to_Keyboard():
    def __init__(self):
        self.curr_queue = [paste()]
        self.max_len = 5
        self.prev_copied = paste()

    def on_activate_copy(self):
        sleep(.1)
        (self.curr_queue, self.prev_copied) = add_to_queue(self.curr_queue, self.max_len, self.prev_copied)

    def on_activate_paste_1(self):
        paste_from_queue(self.curr_queue, 0)

    def on_activate_paste_2(self):
        paste_from_queue(self.curr_queue, 1)

    def on_activate_paste_3(self):
        paste_from_queue(self.curr_queue, 2)

    def on_activate_paste_4(self):
        paste_from_queue(self.curr_queue, 3)

    def on_activate_paste_5(self):
        paste_from_queue(self.curr_queue, 4)

    def on_release(self):
        self.curr_queue = []
        raise sys.exit(1)

###Rough outline -- You can keep up to 5 things copied.
###If you add something to the clipboard, then you should add it to the front
###Of the queue. If there are too many items in the queue, remove the last item
###Before adding the new copied text
def add_to_queue(curr_queue, max_len, prev_copied):
    copied_Text = paste()
    if copied_Text == prev_copied:
        return (curr_queue, prev_copied)
    if len(curr_queue) > max_len:
        curr_queue = [copied_Text] + curr_queue[:4]
        return (curr_queue, copied_Text)
    curr_queue = [copied_Text] + curr_queue
    return (curr_queue, copied_Text)

###This function pastes what you copied in a certain position
def paste_from_queue(curr_queue, pos):
    ###Check that the position is valid
    if pos < 0 or pos >= len(curr_queue):
        return
    copy(curr_queue[pos])
    return

###The program should continuously run in the background and check if new
###Things have been copied without taking up too much computing power
def main():
    react = React_to_Keyboard()
    with keyboard.GlobalHotKeys({
            '<cmd>+c': react.on_activate_copy,
            '<ctrl>+v+q': react.on_activate_paste_1,
            '<ctrl>+v+w': react.on_activate_paste_2,
            '<ctrl>+v+e': react.on_activate_paste_3,
            '<ctrl>+v+r': react.on_activate_paste_4,
            '<ctrl>+v+t': react.on_activate_paste_5,
            '<ctrl>+j': react.on_release}) as h:
        h.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

>
```

Comment: That this isn't _useful_ to anyone without pynput and pyperclip isn't a big problem. But it's very hard to give meaningful feedback without some understanding of how those tools _work_. Obviously this is all very asynchronous; _when_ does _what_ actually happen? Why does `paste_from_queue` call `copy`? You can use `functools.partial` to abstract away the different `on_activate_paste_*` functions. I'm not in a position to comment farther.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I updated my code to use partial functions, which made it much cleaner. I called copy (from the pyperclip library) in paste_from_queue because that function copies the specified text to the clipboard. I'm unsure of a way to directly paste without first copying to the clipboard and then using cmd + v.